# IE Enhanced Security Error while calling Visual Studio Team Services Rest API from BizTalk

Tags: internet-explorer, biztalk, biztalk-2013, azure-devops-rest-api

I am using WCF-WebHttpAdapter to call VSO Rest API from BizTalk.

In the suspended messages I can see the response is HTML which contains the following message:

> Microsoft Internet Explorer's Enhanced Security Configuration is currently enabled on your environment. This enhanced level of security prevents our web integration experiences from displaying or performing correctly. To continue with your operation please disable this configuration or contact your administrator.

I have disabled the security configuration of IE which is confirmed because opening IE also shows a message that it has been disabled.

But still on running the application I am getting the same response back from the API.

I am able to get the correct response in browser or when calling from console application. Problem is only when I am calling from BizTalk